# Get a specific tag name and its value from all resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I need to get a tag name "SquId" and its value of all resource groups in my subscription to a excel sheet. I tried below code.Its giving me all the tags available. But I need to get only specific tags in to excel .Once I get all things in to excel.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

$results = @()

$TagsAsString = ""

$datetime = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yy-hh-mm"

#Getting all Azure Resource

$resources = Get-AzureRmResource

foreach ($resource in $resources) {

#Fetching Tags

$Tags = $resource.Tags

#Checkign if tags is null or have value

if ($Tags -ne $null) {

$Tags.GetEnumerator() | % { $TagsAsString += $_.Key + ":" + $_.Value + ";" }

}

else {

$TagsAsString = "NULL"

}

#Adding to Results

$details = @{

ResourceGroup = $resource.ResourceGroupName

Resource = $resource.Name

Tags = $TagsAsString

}

$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details

#Clearing Variable

$TagsAsString = ""

}

$OutputPathWithFileName = $OutputCSVFilePath + "\Tags-" + $SubscriptionName + "-" + $datetime + ".csv"

$results | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroup, Resource, Tags | export-csv -Path $OutputPathWithFileName -NoTypeInformation

}
```

Comment: Tags can exist at resource group level and resource level. Do want to check both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the script below.

```
$results = @()
$groups = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup 
foreach($group in $groups){
    if($group.Tags.SquId -ne $null){
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    ResourceGroupName = $group.ResourceGroupName;
                    SquId = $group.Tags.SquId
                }
       }
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\tag.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure RM (old):

```
Get-AzureRmTag  -Name "SquId" -Detailed
```

Az:

```
Get-AzTag  -Name "SquId" -Detailed
```